# Can’t create VM in Virt-Manager due to unavailable storage device?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

When I try to create a VM with libvirt, upon reaching the screen that says to allocate storage space, it always says it has an unavailable amount of GiB and doesn’t let me allocate space. When I attempt to do it through the console, it returns with:

```
couldn’t create default storage pool ‘/var/lib/libvirt/images’: could not build storage pool: unable to control COW flag on /var/lib/libvirt/images not btrfs: function not implemented.
```

Here’s an image of what I see:
https://ibb.co/4pRTV4

Sorry if this isn’t a lot to go off, I can provide more info if needed. I’ve been trying to solve this for two days and I’d really appreciate some help.

Comment: The picture is missing

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. You can work around it by specifying a `--file=/home/qemu/file.img` to virt-install. (or wherever you'd like to store your filesystem image)

But it looks like a bug with virsh requiring COW, which needs a btrfs filesystem. And there not being a way to disable COW.

I raised it as a bug here : https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/issues/73

And it is already fixed, just waiting for the new release to make it out to the world now...

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround in virt-manager, the GUI console. Basically, if you create a new VM, you can create a directory storage pool (dir: Filesytem Directory) when you load an ISO file. For this to work, you will need to download an ISO and place it in the directory you will want to use as the storage pool, e.g., `~/VMs/pool1`.

The in virtmanager, click on **Create New Virtual Machine**.

- Choose **Local install media (ISO image or CDROM)**.
- For "In the Choose ISO or CDROM install media", click **Browse...**
- At the bottom, **Browse Local**.
- Navigate to the directory where your ISO is located, again this should be the directory you will want to be the storage pool path, e.g., `~/VMs/pool1`. Click Open on the ISO.
- Choose operating system: Choose what corresponds to the ISO.

At this point I continued down the path of creating a VM: CPU, memory, etc., because that was my goal. But it may not be necessary.

Then if you return to the storage pool dialogue: **Edit** -> **Connection Details** -> **Storage** Tab, you should see the directory (`~/VMs/pool1`)on the left where the ISO was located. At this point you can add volumes and VMs to this storage pool. And also delete/move the ISO file out of it as well.

OS for the host is Debian testing (bulleye), versions:

- libvirt = 6.6.0
- virt-manager = 2.2.1